# Jquery $.ajax() POST

Tags: php, jquery

I cannot seem to get data from an array using the `$.ajax()` function. I am displaying a failure message when access the data name.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "update.php",
    data: { content: $("#textbox").val()}
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

The above code works but when the code in update.php is not pulling the msg and triggering Failure

```
<?php
if(array_key_exists('content', $_POST)){
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Failure";
}
?>
```

the `name: 'content'` should display the content in `#textbox` but it does not.

Comment: Instead of `array_key_exists('content', $_POST)`, try `isset($_POST['content']) && !empty($_POST['content'])`. Also before closing tag of PHP, put exit();

Comment: I edited your question and still I do not understand it. Could you please clarify what "when the code in update.php is not pulling the msg and triggering Failure" means?

Comment: `the name: 'content' should display the content in #textbox but it does not.` - your script does not put `content` into `#textbox` because you're only doing an `alert(...)`.

Comment: Guys, his problem is that PHP is always returning "Failure" - his array_key_exist check ain't working for him

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan at first I thought that you're hinting that `$_POST` is not the `array` type, but only `array`-like type and those two checks would return different results (and honestly I got really scared). I checked the PHP sources and `array_key_exists` in this case must work as well as `isset`. After that I tested OP's code locally and both `var_dump` calls on `array_key_exists('content', $_POST)` and `isset($_POST['content'])` printed out `true`. So I think the problem is somewhere else, not here.

Comment: `array_key_exists` is fine, if a bit unusual. Have you looked at your browser's inspector to see how the request is sent? Have you checked your JavaScript console for errors or warnings?

Comment: Show us form code.

Comment: thanks everyone. in inspect i checked network and the request method is GET. 

here is the form code:

<div class="containerfluid">
        
    <div class="form-group" id="textboxcontainer">
    
        <textarea class="form-control" id="textbox" rows="30"></textarea>
    
    </div>

Comment: Thanks again everyone. I found the problem. It should be type: "POST" not method: "POST"